# unable to install plugins for octobercms

Tags: octobercms

I was wanting to install https://octobercms.com/plugin/garretfick-trustedproxies but it's not immediately obvious to me how to do so. I tried `php artisan plugin:install fideloper.TrustedProxy`, `php artisan plugin:install fideloper/TrustedProxy` and `php artisan plugin:install fideloper-TrustedProxy` and in all instances it says "*A plugin with name "..." could not be found*". Any ideas? Is this plugin, in particular, just not installable?

I'm running OctoberCMS 1.0.443.

Comment: You're using the wrong vendor name, it's GarretFick, not fideloper. Also, upgrade your version of October ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or use this command:

```
php artisan plugin:install GarretFick.Trustedproxies
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the backend.

> 1. login to the backend and navigate to `install plugins`

[image]

> 2. search for plugin `october-trustedproxies` and click on the icon to simply install it.

[image]

and you are done.

if any doubts please comment.